# existence of partial derivatives not closed under composition

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Does there exist two functions, $f$ from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $g$ from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$ such that $f$ and $g$ has all partial derivatives at origin（but not differentiable）but $g\,{o}f$ fail to have partial derivatives at origin?

Answer (score 2):

Yes for geometrical reasons. Consider a function $g=g(x,y)$ that has partial derivatives and is such that the directional derivatives along $(1,1)$ and $(-1,1)$ do not exist. Then take $f$ to be the rotation of the $xy$-plane 45° counterclockwise.

Comment: Thanks！ What about directional derivatives？if f and g has directional derivatives for all direction，can g（f（x，y））fail to have directional derivatives？

Comment: Yes again. Fix a direction $v$ and take a function $g$ which is not differentiable along a curve $\gamma$. And then a function $f$ such that $f(t\vec v)=\gamma(t)$. When you take the directional derivative of $g\circ f$ you really are trying to differentiate $g$ along $\gamma$, but this is not possible by the choice of $g$ you made.

Answer (score 1):

let $$g(x,y) = 
\begin{cases}
\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}  & (x,y)\neq(0,0) \\[2ex]
0 & (x,y)=(0,0)
\end{cases} \quad , \quad f(x,y)=(x,x+y)
$$
directional derivative of $g(x,y)$ at origin in the direction $u=(1,1)$ dose not exist.

and $f(1,0) = (1,1) = u,$  therefore $D_1 g(f(0,0))$ dose not exist:
$$
D_1 g(f(0,0)) = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{g(f(t,0))-0}{t} = 
\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{g(t,t)}{t} = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{1}{2t}
$$
but partial derivatives of $f,g$ in origin exists.